# Monads at the prompt?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is it possible to interact with arbitrary Monad instances incrementally at the GHCi prompt?

You can enter "do" commands interactively:

```
Prelude> x <- return 5
```

But as far as I can tell, everything is forced into the IO () Monad. What if I want to interact with an arbitrary Monad instead?

Am I forced to write the entire sequence of commands inside a giant `do { ... }` and/or use the infix operators directly? That's okay, but I'd much prefer to "enter" an arbitrary monad and interact with it a line at a time.

Possible?

Comment: See ghc trac ticket http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4316

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can. Just annotate your type.
e.g. for the `Maybe Monad`:

```
let x = return 5 :: Maybe Int
```

will result in

```
Just 5
```

Or take the list monad:

```
let x = return 5 :: [Int]
```

will result in

```
[5]
```

Of course you can also play around inside the monad:

```
let x = return 5 :: Maybe Int
x >>= return . (succ . succ)
```

which will result in `Just 7`

Comment: I don't think that's what OP is asking for; the way I read it, he wants the type of the interactive session to be Monad m => m a rather than IO a, not just 'do stuff' with monads.

Comment: @valdermann: you are right... nevertheless I found this very helpful a lot of times and in an active ghci session this is the only way (to my knowledge) to "interact with with an arbitrary monad"

Comment: @oliver Nope, it wasn't quite what I was looking for, but since what I was looking for isn't possible, I guess this is the answer. Typing {it >>= } as a prefix on each line gives some of the incremental feel I want, at the expense of a few keystrokes. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

As things stand, the `IO`-specific behaviour relies on the way `IO` actions are a bit statelike and unretractable. So you can say things like

```
s <- readFile "foo.txt"
```

and get an actual value `s :: String`.

It's pretty clear that it takes more than just `Monad` structure to sustain that sort of interaction. It would not be so easy with

```
n <- [1, 2, 3]
```

to say what *value* n has.

One could certainly imagine adapting ghci to open a prompt allowing a monadic computation to be constructed `do`-style in multiple command-line interactions, delivering the whole computation when the prompt is closed. It's not clear what it would mean to inspect the intermediate values (other than to generate collections of printing computations of type `m (IO ())`, for the active monad `m`, of course).

But it would be interesting to ask whether what's special about `IO` that makes a nice interactive prompt behaviour possible can be isolated and generalized. I can't help sniffing a whiff of a comonadic value-in-context story about interaction at a prompt, but I haven't tracked it down yet. One might imagine addressing my list example by considering what it would mean to have a *cursor* into a space of possible values, the way `IO` has a cursor imposed on it by the here-and-now of the real world. Thank you for the food for thought.

Comment: I see your point. They're a bit too generic. I was specifically wanting to use it for a State monad, though your cursor concept is pretty intriguing too.